# Spring boot, #field is

Tags: java, spring-boot, jsp

I get this error when I use `"${#fields.hasErrors('whatever')}"`

```
The identifier [#fields] is not a valid Java identifier as required by section 1.19 of the EL specification (Identifier ::= Java language identifier). This check can be disabled by setting the system property org.apache.el.parser.SKIP_IDENTIFIER_CHECK to true.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It might be me, but I think you are mixing JSP with Thymeleaf template engines.

Comment: are you not allowed to do that? I want to find a way to throw messages per field instead of giving a error message in the end without stating where the error comes from?

Answer (score 0):

looking at the official thymeleaf documentation, we see this example:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{datePlanted}" />
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('datePlanted')}" th:errors="*{datePlanted}">Incorrect date</p>
```

looking at that example, it seems like you need to put a thymeleaf field (which you passed from your controller and/or get it from a th:object) into the hasErrors bracket but in single quotation marks.

if you already did that, maybe check if you have thymeleaf imported in your html template (i doubt that you forgot that but may still wanna check that) and if thats the case, let me know.